# AS3 - Simple Object Pool example?

Tags: actionscript-3, object, actionscript, pool

thanks in advance for this excellent source of help.

I've been reading a lot about the benefits of Object Pooling. Found some "tutorials" online, all above my skill level. Can anyone please show me an extremely simple example of an Object Pool.

What my game does is creates Ball objects when the user holds down the mouse, stops when user lifts up mouse.

I need to store these Ball objects in an array(or Vector), and hit test them with other objects, removing them from the stage when the hit another object. I'd like to create a pool of say 20 of so, created once, and recycle them.

How would I do this? If you could explain this in a dumbed down way I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks again.

---------Ball Class code---------

ActionScript Code:

```
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;

public class Ball extends Particle {

    public function Ball ($position:Point, $vector:Point, $gravity:int, $friction:Number) {
        super($position, $vector, $gravity, $friction);

        //Set initial position
        x = position.x;
        y = position.y;

        updateTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, setPosition, false, 0, true);

    }

    public function setPosition (e:TimerEvent):void {

        x = position.x;
        y = position.y;

    }
}
```

------------DOCUMENT CLASS CODE ---------------

ActionScript Code:

```
function throwBall(e:TimerEvent):void {

        var tBall:Ball=new Ball(new Point(mouseX,mouseY),new Point(Math.random()+Math.random()*5+Math.random()*8),gravity,friction);
        tBall.gotoAndStop(BallColor);
        addChild(tBall);
        ballArray.push(tBall);

    }
```

Comment: Quite a good post here: http://www.pixelthismobile.com/blog/1/06/2011/elegant-object-pooling-as3

Comment: AdamHarte, the blog post in @pkyeck's answer is much better . . . one of the comments explains using a factory, which is easier to manage in the long run.  Besides, every comment in the pixwlthismobile post seems to be spam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an interesting article about "tweening and object pooling":

http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2008/05/07/tweening-and-object-pools/

Answer (score 0):

I made this that can help you get started:

http://www.plugin.io/2012/11/general-purpose-as3-object-pool/